# Zend: How to add webpage title in all my views?

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, page-title

For now I have to add title in all my views separately like this:

```
<head>
       <title>TestProject - Home</title>
</head>
```

and

```
<head>
       <title>TestProject - Dashboard</title>
</head>
```

Now if I want to change **TestProject** part of title then I have to change it in all my views. How can I mentioned this in **BootStrap.php** and add it in all views? And whenever I have to change this, I will change this in one place.

Comment: i noticed you posted quite few posts, i just want to double check, have you read up on the Zend Quickstart? might help with some of the questions you have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->headTitle('Main Title')->setSeparator(' - ');
}
```

In any **view/.phtml**

```
<?php 
    $this->headTitle()->prepend('Page Title');
    echo $this->headTitle();
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

You should look into the `headTitle` view helper. You can put this snippet below in your bootstrap file (from the documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headtitle).

```
// setting the controller and action name as title segments:
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$this->headTitle($request->getActionName())
     ->headTitle($request->getControllerName());

// setting the site in the title; possibly in the layout script:
$this->headTitle('Test Project');

// setting a separator string for segments:
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' / ');
```

Then you can set each page title individually in controller like this:

```
$this->view->headTitle('The page name')
```

The rendered title will look like this:

```
<title>Test Project / The page name</title>
```

Oh, and you need this in your layout script where the  tag would go:

```
<?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Look into using [layouts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html) and [placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder).  Layouts are applied to all your views, you can set the title there.  In your controller you can then set the "home" or "dashboard" part to a placeholder that will be used by your layout.

Comment: Exactly, this sort of thing is entirely in the View domain (of MVC). Layout would have something like `echo $this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ').prepend('TestProject');`

Answer (score 2):

This is best way to set page title into the controller. If you want to set new title then use..

```
public function init()
 {
    $this->view->headTitle('My title'); 
 }
```

If you want to prepend the title with existing title then use

```
$this->view->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ')->prepend('Manager');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may do this with js as you just site the title =TestProject only then in each page you could with javascript read the title then concatenate the extra title

this if you are using something like master pages