# Zend: How to get view in Bootstrap.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, title

I want to set the title of a web page in Bootstrap. I do something like this in Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {         
    $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
    $view->headTitle( 'My Title' );
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getView() on a non-object in /var/www/student/application/Bootstrap.php on line 7
```

How can I get the view?  I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002123/zend-how-to-add-webpage-title-in-all-my-views/6002198#6002198).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working for me now:

In **Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->headTitle('Main Title')->setSeparator(' - ');
}
```

In any **view/.phtml**

```
<?php 
    $this->headTitle()->prepend('Page Title');
    echo $this->headTitle();
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

@ArneRie is close but got the syntax wrong. This is from the [quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html):

```
protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    // but what you really want is
    $view->headTitle('My title');
}
```

Comment: Sorry: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "view" not found' in /var/www/student/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:692 Stack trace: `

Comment: I don't know what I am missing ?

Comment: @Student To use this answer, you need to configure the view resource in your config file, eg `resources.view[] = ` or even better `resources.view.encoding = "utf-8"`

Answer (score 5):

You are likely trying to access the instance before it was started. Try

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $view = Zend_Layout::startMvc()->getView();
    $view->headTitle( 'My Title' );
}
```

However, `startMVC` can be passed an `$options` argument, which can either be the path to the layout folder as a string or an array or `Zend_Config` instance that will be set to the MVC instance. ZF will usually pass that in automatically at a later stage from your application.ini. I dont know how your application will behave when you dont pass that in.

A better choice would be to have a [**Resource Plugin**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.examples.html) or a [**Controller Plugin**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html). See the linked pages for examples of those and also see the [**source code for `Zend_Layout`**](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Layout.php) for implementation details.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'layout.phtml' not found in path (/var/www/student/application/views/scripts/:/var/www/student/application/modules/institute/views/scripts/:./views/scripts/)' in /var/www/student/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php:980 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/student/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(876): Zend_View_Abstract->_script('layout.phtml') #1 /var/www/student/library/Zend/Layout.php(796):

Comment: @Student this means it is working. It tries to find your layout template in the default path but apparently, you didnt put one there.

Comment: Just use the one from the original documentation as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {         
    $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();
    $view = $bootstrap->getResource('view');
    $view->headTitle( 'My Title' );
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object in /var/www/student/application/Bootstrap.php on line 9

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Invalid method "getBootstrap"`

Comment: May be something missing in my application.ini. I can place my application.ini in my question if you want to see..

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->title = "Edit album";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
```